# ¿Como conectar Liberty Server en eclipse a Oracle?

Tags: oracle, eclipse, jdbc, server

He estado checando varios vídeos, pero no me han servido de mucho porque hacen la conexión directamente y necesito conectar Oracle con Liberty Server para después conectarlo con las clases de Java y estoy muy perdido

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Estoy comenzando un proyecto básico de tipo Maven en Eclipse y quiero conectar Sql Developer con la extensión que ofrece Eclipse de Liberty Server para mostrar en una página web una tabla de usuarios, pero no se como realizar la configuración para la conexión de Sql Developer con Liberty y de ahí conectar una clase Java con Liberty Server para la obtención de datos